# Proper php syntax for html return function

Tags: php, syntax

what is the proper syntax for an if statement inside a php function that is being returned. The static output is how I currently have it but I want to convert it to dynamic output.

This is the static output:

```
function get_html () {
  $output = '';
  $output.= '<div class="commentCount">2</div>';
  return $output;   
}
```

This is the dynamic output:

```
function get_html () {
  $output = '';
  $output.= '<div class="commentCount">
  <?php if ($extractor->isConnected())   {
  // Comment Count
  echo $extractor->commentCount("blog".$id);
  }?></div>';
return $output; 
}
```

Comment: what is being done with the output of `get_html()`? If it's being echo'd to the page, the "dynamic output" won't do what you think.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: You can't use PHP Open Tags in strings. Try to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are not imagining you can send PHP script to the browser to be exeuted there! But this will output the count inside the div if thats what you wanted to do

```
function get_html () {
    $output = '';
    $output.= '<div class="commentCount">';
    if ($extractor->isConnected()) {
        $output .= $extractor->commentCount("blog".$id);
    }
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output; 
}
```

Comment: I was actually imagining to send a php script to the browser and to be executed there together with the whole function but since that is not possible this answer works the best. Instead, I initialized my extractor class in my main page and passed it on as a parameter into my get_html function. Thank you very much for the answer. Cheers.